# 'mpremote' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: python, python-3.x, micropython

I installed python and mpr by using it as well. But now after installing mpr `pip install --user mpr`  and using mpr command I got following error in windows.

```
c:\>mpr version
    
'mpremote' is not recognized as an internal or external command
```

[image]

Comment: hint `$PATH` (or `%PATH%` depending what your OS is)

Comment: I updated the question, as can be seen, mpr is recognized but at same time other commands not working.

Comment: mpr is a wrapper program which depends on mpremote which is part of the micropython project.  Try installing mpremote with pip also.

Answer (score 1):

With Windows, you have to use py.exe and the option -m followed by the module name and any parameters.

Like this:

```
PS C:\> py -m mpremote version
mpremote 0.4.0
```